# Algorithm for generating regex to check if number is in range (ANY RANGE)

Tags: regex, algorithm

I need to have an algorithm for generating regex which will be checking whether number is i in specific range. In general I have following requirements:

- I need to use regex
- Regex need to generated based on given numbers (min and max)
- Need to check only for float numbers
- Numbers migh be positive as well as negative
- Possible float formats: +X.YYY, +X.YY, +X.Y, -X.YYY, -X.YY, -X.Y

  X represents any number of digitts, while Y represent exactly one digit. At least one decimal is needed. So 1 should be 1.0, 0 should be 0.0 and so on.

  Min and max will always have the same format. So you can have min = +2.22, max = +3.45 and check for +1.541 but you cant have min = +2.223, max = +3.45 and check for +1.541

Below you can find examples of ranges:

- from +1.0 to  +20.0
- from -1.0 to +20.0
- from -20.0 to -10.0
- from +1.01 to +2.12

I am not very familiar with regex and to be hoenst I dont even know where should I start. Will appreciate any suggestions!

**MY IDEA**

The idea I have is to create subranges. So say I want to check for range 7.5 - 222.1. Then I believe that I should create subranges and check for them. For example:

- 7.5 - 7.9
- 8.0 - 9.9
- 10.0 - 99.9
- 100.0 - 222.0
- 222.0 - 222.1

Comment: Here's a few suggestions to get you started: 1. Convert your input to string if it's of the float type, 2. If it's a string, implement the regex to check it's format i.e. digits with a dot somewhere within it, 3. Split the string into the integer part and the fractional part - useful to find min and max in range

Comment: Regex is never used to check for ranges. Regex is for pattern matching and not for range checking. Some regex nerds might give you an answer, but it is still not the best way to go about it.

Comment: Hi, thank you! Will try to follow your advice

Comment: Sure vivek_23, I am aware of that. Howerver I have a big feature based on regex and checking for range is only small part of that. Therefore I cant do it other way as it would cost me definitely too much time what I cant afford

Comment: Any requirements for the number of decimals? When range is 1 to 2, is 1.02376831922 a possible match? Are prepadded zeroes OK, like 000001.2? postpadding like 1.2000? Is -0 allowed (if in range)? Is .02 allowed (without the 0 before the decimal separator)? Is the optional + allowed like +1.5? In short, I think this question could be interesting from a theoretical point of view, but it needs a lot more specifications.

Comment: Added more info in description. Lets keep it as simple as possible. Optional + is allowed, maybe it could help to distinguish between negative and positive numbers

Comment: Do you mean with "simple as possible", that the regex may or may not allow padded zeroes, a minus before a single 0, any number of decimals, missing 0 in .1, ...etc?

Comment: I mean that generating such a regex should be as simple as possible. If it is simplier to allow padded zeroes, then its fine. If its not, then skip it. But I believe that it is much simplier to assume that we only have possible values in one of these formats: +X.YYY, +X.YY, +X.Y, -X.Y, -X.YY, -X.YYY

Comment: In that notation X represents any number of digits, while Y represents one digit? I suppose just X would be fine as well (without decimals)? Or is at least one decimal digit required?

Comment: Right, I didn't clarify that, sorry! Exactly, X represents any number of digitts, while Y represent exactly one digit. At least one decimal is needed. So 1 should be 1.0, 0 should be 0.0 and so on. I think the dot separator is needed to separate integer part from fractional part, as kerwei suggested

Comment: I modified description and added some idea of how I imagine it should operate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expression are not really suited for testing whether a number is within some range; they can get quite long.

Below a solution written in a runnable JavaScript snippet. You can enter the range and test value in the input boxes and both the produced regex and validation result for the test value are displayed.

The following assumptions/rules apply:

- When the range is invalid (e.g. minimum number is greater than maximum), then the regex will be `_^` which will make all test values fail.
- Test values must have the same number of decimal digits as the minimum/maximum values.
- When the minimum and maximum have a different number of decimal digits, the greater of the two applies
- `+` is not allowed; non-negative numbers should not have a sign
- `-0.0` is not allowed; zero should not have a sign
- `.9` is not allowed; there should be at least one digit before the decimal point
- The rules for the minimum/maximum values are less strict.
- minimum and maximum do not need to have the same number of integer digits. For example, a range from -33.08 to 12328.84 will work fine.

```js
// Some helper constants/functions for producing regex
const reDot = "\\.";

function reRange(low, high) {
    return high-low === 9 ? "\\d" : low<high ? "[" + low + "-" + high + "]" : low;
}

function reRepeat(what, min, max=min) {
    return !max ? ""
        : what + (max > 1 ? "{" + min + (min < max ? "," + max : "") + "}" : min ? "" : "?");
}

function reOr(list) {
    return list.length > 1 ? "(" + list.join("|") + ")" : list[0];
}

function reAnchor(what) {
    return "^" + what + "$";
}

// Main function:
function rangeRegex(min, max) {
    if (!(+min <= +max)) return "_^"; // All strings should fail this regex
    const decimals = Math.max( (min+".").split(".")[1].length, (max+".").split(".")[1].length );
    // Take care of negative ranges:
    if (+min < 0 && +max < 0) return reAnchor("-" + positiveRange(-max, -min));
    if (+min < 0) return reAnchor(reOr(["-(?=.*[1-9])" + positiveRange(0, -min), positiveRange(0, max)]));
    return reAnchor(positiveRange(min, max));
    
    function positiveRange(min, max) {
        // Format the two input numbers with equal number of decimals and remove decimal point
        const minParts = (Math.abs(min)+".").split(".");
        const maxParts = (Math.abs(max)+".").split(".");
        min = minParts[0] + minParts[1].padEnd(decimals, "0"); 
        max = maxParts[0] + maxParts[1].padEnd(decimals, "0");
        // Build regex parts
        const parts = [];
        if (min.length < max.length && !/^1?0*$/.test(min)) {
            parts.push(fixedLengthRange(min, "9".repeat(min.length)));
            min = "1" + "0".repeat(min.length);
        }
        if (min.length < max.length && !/^9+$/.test(max)) {
            parts.push(fixedLengthRange("1" + "0".repeat(max.length-1), max));
            max = "9".repeat(max.length-1);
        }
        if (/^1?0*$/.test(min) && /^9+$/.test(max)) {
            parts.push(
                reRange(min[0], 9) 
                    + reRepeat(reRange(0, 9), min.length-decimals-1, max.length-decimals-1)
                    + (decimals ? reDot + reRepeat(reRange(0, 9), decimals) : "") 
            );
        } else {
            parts.push(fixedLengthRange(min, max));
        }
        return reOr(parts);
    }
    
    function fixedLengthRange(min, max) {
        const len = max.length;
        if (!len) return "";
        const pre = len === decimals ? reDot : "";
        let low = +min[0];
        let high = +max[0];
        if (low === high) return pre + min[0] + fixedLengthRange(min.slice(1), max.slice(1));
        const parts = [];
        if (+min.slice(1)) {
            parts.push(min[0] + fixedLengthRange(min.slice(1), "9".repeat(len-1)));
            low++;
        }
        if (max.slice(1) < "9".repeat(max.length-1)) {
            parts.push(max[0] + fixedLengthRange("0".repeat(len-1), max.slice(1)));
            high--;
        }
        if (low <= high) {
            parts.push(reRange(low, high) + 
                (len <= decimals || !decimals ? reRepeat(reRange(0, 9), len-1)
                : reRepeat(reRange(0, 9), len-1-decimals) + reDot + reRepeat(reRange(0, 9), decimals)));
        }
        return pre + reOr(parts);
    }
}

// I/O handling for this snippet

const inputMin = document.querySelector("#min");
const inputMax = document.querySelector("#max");
const inputVal = document.querySelector("#val");
const outputRegex = document.querySelector("#regex");
const outputValid = document.querySelector("#valid");

document.oninput = function() {
    const regex = rangeRegex(inputMin.value, inputMax.value);
    outputRegex.textContent = regex;
    outputValid.textContent = new RegExp(regex).test(inputVal.value) ? "OK" : "Not OK";
}
```

```html
<label>Min: <input id="min"></label>
<label>Max: <input id="max"></label>
<hr>
<div>Regex: <span id="regex"></span></div>
<label>Test: <input id="val"></label>
<div>Valid: <span id="valid"></span></div>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! I came to very similar approach in Java but my code was not able to deal with negative values and had some flaws :/
There is one thing which might be improved. Instead of generating \d{n} it might be \d*
However it will fail for typing 1.5 in range 1.00 - 1.50

Comment: You're welcome! Indeed, I had assumed the number of decimals had to be limited to 1, 2 or 3 (cf "possible float formats" in your question). It would be a different story if the number of decimals should not be restricted.

Comment: Thats true, I didnt specify. But having your algorithm I will modify it slightly :)
Have a nice day!